# How do I access xsd value using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following xsd file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"     elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="order">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ordername" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />

    <xs:element name="articles">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="article">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="Account" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="1|5|7|9"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>                       
                <xs:element name="Vat" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="1|2|3"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>                       

              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am trying to access all allowed patterns for a specific element. In this case I would like to find the allowed pattern for "Account" which should give me "1|5|7|9". Ideally I would like to be able to directly access the value, something like this...

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(fileName);

            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

            var nodeToAccess = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("order/articles/article/Account", nsmgr);
```

But that does not work, can anyone please show the proper way to do this?

Comment: XPath works on nodes, not on the name attributes of nodes. So you'd need something more like `element[@name="order"]//element[@name="articles"]` etc. Consider reading [some documentation about XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath), maybe find an online utility that will interactively match your XPath to an example document, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath for this:

```
    var nodeToAccess = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//xs:element[@name='Account']/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction/xs:pattern", nsmgr);
    if (nodeToAccess != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nodeToAccess.Attributes["value"].Value);
    }
```

Comment: But do note that this is incredibly fragile. If the schema is refactored and expressed in a different way, for example to use global type declarations rather than local type declarations, then your code will break. Only you can judge whether this matters; but creating a dependency on the internal detail of the schema in this way is not sound engineering.